# Functional equation with integral inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Given the function $f:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$.

a) $f$ is an increasing function

b) $F(0)=0$ and $F(x+y)\le F(x)+F(y)$ for all $x,y$ in the domain. ($F$ is the primitive of $f$)

Find $f$. Can somebody help me with some ideas, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

Let $$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$

then for $x\ge y\ge 0$,

$$F(x+y)-F(y)=\int_y^{x+y}f(t)dt$$

$$=\int_0^xf(t+y)dt$$

thus

$$F(x+y)-F(y)-F(x)=\int_0^x(f(t+y)-f(t))dt\ge 0$$